# main page boxes not aligned right in Internet Explorer

Tags: css, internet-explorer-9, css-float

I am building a photo portfolio website using wordpress and editing an existing theme. I worked on it in firefox and checked a few times throughout at the styling in IE and it was always fine. But having basically finished I looked at it today and it in IE and it is totally messed up. None of the boxes on the main page are lined up right.

I tried using the code in the header to have IE render it as IE7 and that generally worked but it made some other little problems. I am not sure if the problem is my doctype. I don't really know what it should be, or if I changed something along the way that messed it up.

The site works perfectly in all other browsers that I have tried

Here is the site. http://theshalomimaginative.com/blog/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youre `<h3>` tags aren't closed. One of the few instances where IE is actually rendering things correctly ;) Other browsers will allow us to make mistakes like this, but IE is more strict.

Never forget the value of validating your code!

Comment: we all do from time to time! if you wouldn't mind, please check the answer answered :)